# What are good resources for playing Lizardfolk characters?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races, lizardfolk

Are there any good official resources (racial feats or class substitutions) for Lizardfolk characters in 3.5? Races of Eberron threw goblinoids and orcs a bone but nothing for the poor denizens of Q'barra. I'll be playing in Eberron but non-setting specific resources are fine. I don't imagine there's much but there's gotta be something and I'm having no luck finding anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beyond BESW's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37715/8610) of *Savage Species* and *Serpent Kingdoms* containing mechanics that *can* be employed by lizardfolk but aren't *exclusive* to them

## There's Very Little

Few attempts were made to make *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* lizardfolk interesting, which is kind of a shame, really, for an iconic creature with over 30 years of history.<sup>1</sup>

- The *Player's Guide to Faerûn* contains the regional feats Axe Thrower (33), Dauntless (37), and Tireless (46), which, while not exclusive to lizardfolk, *are* restricted to characters from specific regions, and one of those regions is the civilized lizardfolk marsh city of Surkh. These are... actually pretty good for the right characters, except the feat Dauntless; don't take that.
- *Dragon* #334's article "Ecology of the Lizardfolk" (52-7) has the lizardfolk-as-a-prerequisite feats Chameleon Blood (56) and Reptilian Healing (57). Both are... unspectacular.

I am unaware of any lizardfolk racial substitution levels published by Wizards of the Coast.

**Unofficial Sources**
In fact, even *DandDWiki* lists no entries for *homebrew* lizardfolk [racial substitution levels](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Category:Racial_Substitution_Levels). There are a *few* 3rd-party products for those who want more lizardfolk crunch. Mongoose's [*Slayer's Guide to Lizardfolk*](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/1460/Slayers-Guide-to-Lizardfolk?it=1) contains 4 feats, none of which are exclusive to lizardfolk, and the lizardfolk-exclusive prestige classes stillguard and scaled king, both of which are unimpressive. Paradigm Concepts published [*Ssethregore: In the Coils of the Serpent*](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product_reviews_info.php?&reviews_id=12738&products_id=20093&it=1), an entire empire ruled by non-product-identity lizard types, for the Arcanis setting; *Ssethregore* apparently contains feats, prestige classes, and so on, but I've not seen it--maybe someone who has could Comment on it.

---

1. In the *Player's Handbook* (1978) the 7th-level druid spell *reincarnate* (64) and the 6th-level magic-user spell *reincarnate* (85-6) could bring a dead character back as even a dryad (!) or an ogre mage (!!), respectively, but neither spell could bring a dead creature back as a lizard man (calling them *folk* came later--hey, it was a different time). Despite this, the *Rogue's Gallery* (1980) had Jeff R. Leason's character [Phoebus](http://www.canonfire.com/wiki/index.php?title=Phoebus) (44-5) brought back from the dead as a lizard man; Jeff Dee's illustration of ol' Phoebus wielding a trident captured my 12-year-old imagination. But I did always wonder how that happened when that actually *couldn't* be rolled.

   In *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* there's only a 1% chance a creature who's the target of the 4th-level Drd spell *reincarnate* [trans] (*PH* 270) gaining a new young adult lizardfolk body. There's a higher chance of getting a *kobold* body than a lizardfolk one. But, y'know, at least there *is* a chance.

Comment: I really love the regional feats. They make the region of origin choice more mechanically relevant, which is something I think is missing from 3.5 Eberron. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 5):

The "Serpent Kingdoms" book (early 3.5, with lots of 3.0 relics) has some features for lizardy folks. It's poorly laid out so it's hard to be sure, but I don't see anything *specifically* for lizardfolk; instead it's got options for "Scaled Ones," which is a generic term for sapient serpenty peoples including lizardfolk. Mostly it's got a handful of feats, but there are also some amusing equipment options for Scaled Ones.

The 3.0 "Savage Species" manual has some more useful-but-nonspecific features which lizardfolk can take advantage of via their more generic racial features like natural attacks. It is 3.0, so some of its mechanics will need massaging in order to fit a 3.5 campaign.

Comment: Never heard of Serpent Kingdoms; checked it out and I definitely love it. Yuan-ti are another race I wished got more love.